# qtablewidget example for entering data into the table

Tags: qtablewidget

I need to create a tablewidget with 3 columns and multiple rows…
I was able to create the columns and headers but Iam unable to enter data into the table…
So please help me as soon as possible…
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps (20 rows, 3 columns, with text - cellID, in every cell).
If you need something else, feel free to ask...

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class Table(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout() 

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(20)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.enterDataInTable()

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def enterDataInTable(self):  
        for i in range(0,20):
            for j in range(0,3):
                self.table.setItem(i, j, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("cell %s-%s"%(i+1,j+1)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        t = Table()
        t.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```